# Managing a ClearCase Snapshot View with Remote Server

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have a snapshot view of a project of tens of thousands of files. I work remotely and a live view wouldn't be practical. I am only testing with these files, so I never have to put something back, but I do want to be able to get any files that have changed.

The way it has been explained to me is that there is no mechanism in ClearCase to identify my out-of-date files or to automatically update them when I would request an update of just those files.

The only option I have is to replace the entire snapshot, which could mean waiting a very long time for it to download (even when I am on the local network and not working remotely). Even then, I wouldn't know which files were updated since my existing snapshot was made.

I'm new to ClearCase, but have used SVN. SVN has this capability to see which files are out of date and to request an update of just those files.

Is there a way, with ClearCase, to get what I want? I feel (or want to think) that I may be misinformed about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The [`cleartool update`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) command using `-print` option:

*-print   Produces a preview of the update operation: instead of copying or removing files, update prints a report to standard output the actions it would take for each specified element.*

That should suffice to know what's changed and if you need to update.

btw: **the update may analyze the entire view, but only actually downloads files that have changed.**

**update**

*Updates elements in a snapshot view
[...]
Updating Loaded Elements
For one or more loaded elements, the update command does the following:*

**  Reevaluates the config spec to select versions of loaded elements in
   the VOB and loads them if they differ from the currently loaded
   versions*

You could also work more effectively by using [labels](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-41) or [baselines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-14). If you only update after a particular baseline, you could run [`cleartool diffbl`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm) to find the differences between the current and latest. You could then just monitor for a new baseline. Or you can use [`cleartool lsact -l`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-8) to examine the element versions on the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option of using the ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC)?  It is designed to efficiently support high-latency (i.e. WAN) connections to the ClearCase servers.  See the ClearCase Knowledge Center:

[Developing software with Rational ClearTeam Explorer](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccrc_dev_container.htm?lang=en)

CCRC supports both Web views (similar to snapshot views) and automatic views (similar to dynamic views) and provides much better performance than CCLC (the "ClearCase Local Client" that supports snapshot and dynamic views) over a high-latency network.

The command line interface for CCRC (rcleartool) supports the 'update' operation as does the ClearTeam Explorer GUI.  The update operation evaluates which versioned files have changed and only updates that subset.